# How to get ControlTemplate not to override DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Similar to gmail's Select button, I wanted to create a `ComboBox` for the `ListView` which allows the user to quickly select entries of their choosing (ex. All, None, Read, Unread). However, the selected value would display a tri-state `CheckBox` equivalent to All, Some, or None of the entries being selected. I succeeded in doing so. Below is the xaml for an example Window utilizing this feature<sup><sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup></sup>:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTest.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfTest="clr-namespace:WPFTest.ViewModels"
        xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Desktop"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest.Models"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="WPF Test" Height="221.256" Width="605"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfTest:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary
                    Source="/WPFTest;Component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEntry}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Margin="10">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox 
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" 
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.RowSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <ComboBox 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Options.Items}"
                                SelectedValue="{Binding Options.SelectedItem}"
                                ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource itemTemplateSelector}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="44" 
                                Height="34"
                                FontSize="20"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                                <ComboBox.Resources>
                                    <DataTemplate x:Key="selectedTemplate">
                                        <TextBlock 
                                            x:Name="displayText"
                                            Text="{Binding DataContext.Options.SelectedDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                                            FontSize="20"
                                            Height="22"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:Key="dropDownTemplate">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="12"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                    <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector
                                        x:Key="itemTemplateSelector"
                                        SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource selectedTemplate}"
                                        DropDownTemplate="{StaticResource dropDownTemplate}"/>
                                </ComboBox.Resources>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="Auto"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Header="Type"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Demo choosing options in combo]

Recently I was asked to make a style for every `ComboBox` on our screens - changing their backgrounds. Because I'm on Windows8, setting the Background alone isn't enough. Using [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24240.changing-the-background-color-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8.aspx) I was able to create the `ControlTemplate` to get the correct behavior, with one minor error fix:

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="True"/>
    <!-- Comment out the following, it throws an error. -->
    <!--<Condition>
            <Condition.Value>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </Condition.Value>
        </Condition>-->
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
```

And usage:

```
<Style
    TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    ...
    <Setter
        Property="Template"
        Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle1}" />
</Style>
```

This successfully styles the ComboBox Background. However, revisiting the former screen, I noticed that this breaks my gmail-like display.

[image: Background colored but display is wrong]

How can I get this `ControlTemplate` and the dynamic `DataTemplate` to cooperate?

<sup><sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> ViewModels and Models can be provided if necessary for a solution. Or see [full working example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ac9c753b0f42709a502).</sup>

Comment: You want that your style for ComboBox doesn`t apply for gmail-like ComboBox at all or only template property?

Comment: @galakt I want the gmail-like ComboBox to also have the background ControlTemplated style.

Comment: Can i ask you, why you don't want to make unique style for gmail-like combobox and set him manually?

Comment: This was the only way I could get a Background style to work in Windows 8.  Even setting `Template = "{StaticBinding ComboBoxStyle1}"` on *only this* ComboBox didn't work. Which is sad really... you'd think `Background = "SomeColorOrStyle"` would suffice.

Comment: I mean copy your current style for combobox and paste with x:key and without Template Setter. And on your gmail combobox set Style binding

Comment: I mean <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="gmailStyle">
    ...
</Style>  and <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource gmailStyle}"/>

Comment: @galakt I believe I misunderstood what you fully meant before. Thanks for the help! I think I've implemented what you were getting at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Color the Background**

As per the OP, following [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24240.changing-the-background-color-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8.aspx), you generate the `ControlTemplate`.

> To do this, you can right-click on the ComboBox element in design mode
>   in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 and select the “Edit template” option
>   and then the “Edit a copy…” option.

Again note the bug fix from the OP. Changing the background can then be done by:

```
<Border 
    x:Name="templateRoot"
    BorderBrush="#FFACACAC"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    Background="{StaticResource MyComboBackgroundBrush}"> <!-- option 1 -->

    <!-- <Border.Background> -->

         <!-- option 2 -->
         <!-- <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>-->

         <!-- option 3 -->                     
         <!-- <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/> -->

    <!-- </Border.Background>
         <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
             <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="F1M0,0L2.667,2.66665 5.3334,0 5.3334,-1.78168 2.6667,0.88501 0,-1.78168 0,0z" Fill="#FF606060" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Border> -->
</Border>
```

**Interact with the DataTemplate**

1. In the resource file, following the above instructions, you declared:

   ```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplateBasic" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
       ...
       <ContentPresenter 
           x:Name="contentPresenter"
           ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
           ... />
       ...
   </ControlTemplate>
   ```

   Create a copy of it with the following change, where `selectedTemplate` is the `key` of the `DataTemplate` you want to cooperate with the `ControlTemplate`:

   ```
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplateHeader" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
       ...
       <ContentPresenter 
           x:Name="contentPresenter"
           ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource selectedTemplate}" 
           ... />
       ...
   </ControlTemplate>
   ```
2. Declare the appropriate styles:

   ```
   <Style
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
       <Setter Property="Template"
               Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxControlTemplateBasic}" />
       <!-- other generic style setters -->
   </Style>

   <Style
       x:Key="ComboBoxHeader"
       x:Name="ComboBoxHeader"
       TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
       <Setter Property="Template"
               Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxControlTemplateHeader}" />
       <Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector"
               Value="{DynamicResource itemTemplateSelector}"/>
       <!-- other specific style setters -->
   </Style>
   ```

**Results**

- Every `ComboBox` shares the same look.
- The dynamic use of `DataTemplate` `selectedTemplate` allows each `ListView` header gmail-like `ComboBox` to have the same look with unique binding values.

Take for example the OP `ComboBox` header plus the following `ComboBox` with the same item source:

```
<ComboBox 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="10,152,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="120"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Options.Items}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Options.SelectedItem}"/>

<GridViewColumnHeader>
    <ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Options.Items}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Options.SelectedItem}"
        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxHeader}">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="selectedTemplate">
                <TextBlock 
                    x:Name="displayText"
                    Text="{Binding DataContext.Options.SelectedDisplay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Height="22"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="dropDownTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="12"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <local:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector
                x:Key="itemTemplateSelector"
                SelectedTemplate="{StaticResource selectedTemplate}"
                DropDownTemplate="{StaticResource dropDownTemplate}"/>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
</GridViewColumnHeader>
```

[image: working example]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you doing so complicated `ComboBox` - you defined `ItemTemplateSelector` twice...

Ok - here is my 2 cents: `ComboBox` is lookless control. It based on `ControlTemplate` target type = ComboBox. Inside `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate` you will find `ContentPresenter`. Whatever coming into `Content` of `ContentPresenter` could be styled with `DataTemplate`. Generally - when you define `DataTemplate` it *wrap* only `ContentPresenter` or `ItemsPresenter` for range based controls - not the whole `ControlTemplate` obviously.

So if you want to change 'Selected' template for `ComboBox` is ok but all other data should be defined via `DataTemplate` for this type `{x:Type local:SomeType}` that will be used by `ComboBox`.

Also - consider using @galakt suggestion: use `Style` with `TargetType` - it easy to read, refactor, find, understand...

Comment: While I do not see where I doubled-up on `ItemTemplateSelector` - your mention of the `ContentPresenter` pointed me in the correct investigative direction. While your answer did not immediately alert me what to do, I now see how it relates to the solution I came up with. +1 Thanks for the directional nudge!